# X11 Consolas regular looks ugly

Tags: debian, x11, fonts

I'm using Debian 9 with KDE and I need normal Consolas fonts in my system. First after installation I hadn't any Consolas font installed so I downloaded it, opened and just clicked *install*. And what I noticed is that regular and bold variation of font looks almost the same. So I installed `font-manager`, downloaded all 4 variations fro, the Microsoft site and installed them via font-manager, after that Consolas became looks brilliant but after restarting machine it gone back to ugly-looking and now I can't make it looks good again. Bold looks even better. What can I do?

**Regular**

[image]

**Bold**

[image]

Comment: I can't answer your question specifically, but why do you need Consolas?

Comment: In the font section of the system settings, did you choose anti-aliasing independent from the size?

Comment: @Philippos I need to use Consolas in apps like Sublime etc, that setting allows me to adjust anti-aliasing of fonts used for OS elements...

Comment: @Daria In this case I don't understand how KDE is involved. Sublime uses X11 directly, right?

Comment: @Philippos I don't complain on KDE, just added for information. And problem is not only in Sublime, but in all apps that uses it. As you see on a screenshots, the font looks bad in font-manager too

Comment: Try to set font hinting to slight in system settings, don't forget to restart the session afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

The Consolas font was designed with hinting that looks bad in some rendering engines.

[image]

The only way around this is to somehow change to [another font](https://typedesign.repl.co/dmcasansserif.html):

[image]

If your applications specifically require a Consolas font, then the only option is to rename any font to Consolas and then use it.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem. I solved this by changing the hinting to slight systemwide, and also in `.Xresources` file. I use KDE, so I went to "Fonts" section of my KDE settings, and set hinting to "slight". XFCE also has similar settings. Not so sure about MATE and GNOME though.

Full hinting (ugly):

[image: Full hinting (ugly)]

Slight hinting (good):

[image: Slight hinting (good)]

Font size in image is 13.0